# Understanding thermal wavelength and de Broglie thermal wavelength

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

One of the areas in which the concept of de Broglie wavelength is important has to do with the fact that if the interparticle distance of a 3D gas is larger than the thermal de Broglie wavelength then it can be treated with the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. Here, the thermal de Broglie is basically the average de Broglie wavelength for the gas particles at a certain temperature.

Recently, I was watching a lecture where the lecturer mentioned that for a dilute gas:

> The de Broglie wavelength of the particles is less than the thermal wavelength

I think I understand what this means. He is saying that the wavepackets of the particles are localized so they are far apart and rarely collide even with the thermal fluctuations.

I want to know whether in the above quote the thermal wavelength is the same as the thermal de Broglie wavelength or some other wavelength.

I understand the interparticle distance vs Thermal de Broglie wavelength argument but never heard of the individual particle de broglie wavelength vs thermal wavelenght argument.